# Java Constructor help

Tags: java, constructor

```
//*******************************************************
// Account.java
//
// A bank account class with methods to deposit to, withdraw from,
// change the name on, and get a String representation
// of the account.
//*******************************************************
import java.util.Random;
public class Account
{
  private double balance;
  private String name;
  private long acctNum;

  //----------------------------------------------
  //Constructor -- initializes balance, owner, and account number
  //----------------------------------------------
  public Account(double initBal, String owner, long number)
  {
    balance = initBal;
    name = owner;
    acctNum = number;
  }

  //----------------------------------------------
  // Checks to see if balance is sufficient for withdrawal.
  // If so, decrements balance by amount; if not, prints message.
  //----------------------------------------------
  public void withdraw(double amount)
  {
    if (balance >= amount)
       balance -= amount;
    else
       System.out.println("Insufficient funds");
  }
//----------------
//Track how many accounts
//----------------
    private static int numAccounts=0;
    {
        numAccounts++;
        }
    public static int getNumAccounts()
    {
        return numAccounts;
        }

  //----------------------------------------------
  // Adds deposit amount to balance.
  //----------------------------------------------
  public void deposit(double amount)
  {
    balance += amount;
  }

  //----------------------------------------------
  // Returns balance.
  //----------------------------------------------
  public double getBalance()
  {
    return balance;
  }
// Get name of account
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
    //----------------------------------------------
  // Returns account number.
  //----------------------------------------------

  public long getAcctNumber()
  {
    return acctNum;
  }

//----------------
//Void and close the accounts
//----------------

    public void close()
{
    balance = 0;
    name += "CLOSE";
     numAccounts--;
     }

//----------------
//Consolidating accounts
//----------------
    public static Account consolidate(Account acct1,Account acct2)
    { Account newAccount=null;
        if((acct1.getName()).equals(acct2.getName()))
        if(acct1.getAcctNumber()!=acct2.getAcctNumber())
            {newAccount= new Account(acct1.getBalance()+acct2.getBalance(),String owner);

                        Random generator = new Random();
            acctNum= generator.nextInt();
                acct1.close();
                acct2.close();
     }
     else
     System.out.println("Not allow,same account number");
     else
     System.out.println("Can't use other people account");
     return newAccount;
    }


 //----------------------------------------------
  // Returns a string containing the name, account number, and balance.
  //----------------------------------------------
  public String toString()
  {
    return "Name: " + name + 
"\nAccount Number: " + acctNum +
"\nBalance: " + balance; 
  }
}
```

Please look at the //consolidate section. What I'm trying to do is, consolidate acct1 and acct2 into one new account, with the restrictions that is acct1 and acct2 has to has the same name, acct1 and acct2 account number has to be different from each other, and if those are met, create a new account with a new balance from the two old account, keep the same name and also randomly generate a new account number. Is there something missing in my code? It wont compile. These are errors i got

```
    Account.java:95: ')' expected
                {newAccount= new Account(acct1.getBalance()+acct2.getBalance(),String owner);
                                                                                     ^
    Account.java:95: illegal start of expression
                {newAccount= new Account(acct1.getBalance()+acct2.getBalance(),String owner);
                                                                                           ^
```

Comment: next time please tag your question as homework if it is  (this time I'll do it) and format your code so it'll be readable (use the buttons above the text box).

Comment: This looks _very_ similar to [your other question from a few hours ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5625314/method-of-overload) (and, for that matter, [your question from an hour before that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5624239/why-isnt-this-creating-an-object)). Could you pick one to edit with updates, to keep things in one place?

Comment: Yea it's the same one, sorry, didnt know if i should edited the old one or make a new one

Answer (score 5):

`String owner` should just be `acct1.getName()` or whatever function retrieves the name.

Also, the line `acctNum = generator.nextInt();` will fail as `acctNum` isn't defined in that context. Furthermore, you don't set the account number of `newAccount` to be this `acctNum` variable.

I suggest you change it to this:

`newAccount.setAcctNumber(generator.nextInt());`

Comment: If i do newAccount.setAcctNumber(generator.nextInt());

Then wouldnt I hace to make a setAcctNumber too some where in the constructor?

Comment: Not in the constructor - rather, in the body of the `Account` class you would declare a method with a signature `void setAcctNumber(int number) {this.acctNumber = number;}`

Answer (score 0):

The compile error at the line

`newAccount= new Account(acct1.getBalance()+acct2.getBalance(),String owner)`

is because `String owner` is a declaration that should be used in a method signature, as you did above. When you actually make a call to the constructor, though, you need to send a `String` parameter in.

The compiler is complaining because what you are actually doing at this line is declaring a `String` variable named `owner`. Java won't allow that in a method call.

Finbarr is right; use the method to get the name of the account instead.

Comment: What about if I want to generate a random number for the new consolidated account? I couldn't figure how to do it within that section